# Searching for Microsoft Access records in a C# Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

How to search for a Microsoft Access record in a C# Windows Forms application?

Code:

```
    private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from  tblStudents WHERE studid='" + 
                                             txtstudid.Text + "' ",
                                           conn);
        dataset = new DataSet();

        dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
    }
```

Comment: You should format code by putting four spaces before each line. You can also select it and click the `{}` button. More helpful tips at the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page. Also, tell us what's wrong. We can't help you if we don't know what you need help with.

Comment: I've edited your question so that the code block is readable. Even with that, I cannot figure out what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: i want search record and searched record is display in the datagridview

Comment: What specific issue are you having trouble with?

Comment: Is this a question? or this a news about you creating a new project? :D what's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
//BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

//set the BindingSource DataSource
bSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

//set the DataGridView DataSource
dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
```

To get the changes back into the database, all you have to do is call the `Update()` of the `OleDbDataAdapter` with the `DataTable` as the argument to accomplish this.

```
da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: when run it shows error in da.Fill(ds) (error: OleDbException was unhandled )